# Sorting an ArrayList of Hashmap<String,Object> by int value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I've been searching a lot but I didn't find a suitable solution to my problem. Now I want to sort an `ArrayList<Hashmap<String, Object>>` according to an int value.

```
HashMap<String, Object>map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("friend", "x");
map.put("status", "yyoyo");
map.put("time", "20:10");
map.put("lat", 30.030535);
map.put("lng", 31.506050);
map.put("distance", 50); 
statusMapList.add(map);
```

Now, this is a sample here. the `statusMapList` holds many Hashmaps like this, and I want to sort them according to the `distance` value, so is there any way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your use case correctly, you should change your data representation.

Create a class called Status that implements Comparable

```
public class Status implements Comparable<Status>
{
 String friend;
 String status;
 String time; // Or DateTime
 double lat;
 double lng;
 double distance;

// Override compareTo and use distance to decide the order
// Override equals
// Override hashcode
}
```

And now you should create an `ArrayList<Status>()` and then `Collections.sort()` should work.

Comment: +1 For suggesting creating a class. (Personally, I would prefer `double` over `Double`.)

Comment: @srikfreak  can you tell me what's wrong about working this way:

`public class PositionComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>> {
     @Override
  public int compare(HashMap<String, Object> o1, HashMap<String, Object> o2) {
         return ((Double)(o1.get("distanceFromMe"))).compareTo((Double)(o2.get("distanceFromMe")));
     }
 }`

Comment: @Code-Guru - yeah, I agree. Without knowing anything more about the usecase, I should be using primitive types. Updated.

Comment: @OmArHesham There's nothing *wrong* with using a HashMap per se. However, Object Oriented programming offers other options which can make your code more flexible. In this case, creating a class allows you to sort your List with a lot less hassle.

Comment: @OmArHesham - Your way of using HashMap 'works' but is not very elegant. It is hard to understand and not flexible. When you know the structure of Status, you should make it an object and use OOP to model it. You will benefit from it in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Just write you own [`Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [this version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) of `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Sorry, but I have a huge problem with dealing with Comparators. can you do me a favour and give me an example to how this would work for me? Thanks alot

Comment: The other two answers might be better in an OOP way, so if you could use an object to represent the data, please do so. However, if this is a homework that you don't have control over, you could just return map1.get("distance") - map2.get("distance") in the compareTo of the comparator class.

Comment: and what about the following solution:
`public class PositionComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>> {
     @Override
  public int compare(HashMap<String, Object> o1, HashMap<String, Object> o2) {
         return ((Double)(o1.get("distanceFromMe"))).compareTo((Double)(o2.get("distanceFromMe")));
     }
 }`

Comment: @OmArHesham That looks generally ok. Does it work for you? If yes, why do you ask? If not, what's wrong? Also, I thought that you use `"distance"` and not `"distanceFromMe"`.